# Querying multiple MS SQL database instances on the same machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to MS SQL and I am trying to do something that seems simple but is driving me crazy.

I want to write a query to pull data from two databases. Each database is on a different instance on the same DEV machine. (one is MS SQL 2008 and the other MS SQL 2005). I am using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (MSSMS).

I have the basics figured out. I know the format of the query and what I need to do. My big problem is figuring out what the NAME of each server is?

```
SELECT LastName
  FROM [servername1].CHA2.dbo.Customer
UNION  
SELECT LastName
  FROM [servername2].OBXKites.dbo.Contact
ORDER BY LastName
```

I used the server name that I connect to `MSSMS (DLPT\HENRY)` with and what is also returned by `@@SERVERNAME`

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME returns DLPT\HENRY
```

I tried

> DLPT\HENRY.CHA2.dbo.Customer

did not work

> I tried it without the DLPT HENRY.CHA2.dbo.Customer

did not work

I need to future out what the NAME of the server is to use in the query.

Comment: You need to use a linked server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
[DLPT\HENRY].CHA2.dbo.Customer
```

The namo contains a backslash which is normally illegal in an identifier. You surround illegal names with brackets.

Note that you surround just the server name. In other words, it is [DLPT\HENRY].CHA2.dbo.Customer, not [DLPT\HENRY.CHA2.dbo.Customer].

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Linked servers. Then only different instances of SQL Server are able to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't access tables in databases in separate SQL Server instances by default. You have a couple of options here - neither are simple and might require help from a DBA:

1) Use linked servers like this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782(v=sql.110).aspx

Then you will be able to refer to the second table in the format INSTANCENAME.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName

2) Use replication to get the table from the second database into the first database. Then the contents of the second table will be synched to the first database in more or less real time

[Read about SQL Replication here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=SQL.105).aspx)